# Валидация JPEG для поиска "битых" изображений

Tags: алгоритм, валидация, jpeg

PHP скрипт возвращает изображения, расположенные на другом диске, через установку заголовка `header('Content-type: image/jpg');` и отправку контента посредством `echo file_get_contents(...);`. Изображения постоянно добавляются и берётся рандомное при каждом вызовы скрипта.

Так уж вышло, что клиентская программа, что отправляет фотки на сервер, получила патч с багом, и сервер наполнился битыми jpg-ами, причём не все подряд испорченные, а кому как повезло.

При просмотре изображений в браузере битые либо отображаются как серый фон, либо вот так:

[image: view_error]

Причём ту же картинку IrfanView "видит" так:

[image: if_view]

Будет код для прохода по диску и удаления битых jpeg.

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно программно проверить корректный ли jpeg файл или нет, чтобы скрипт нормальные фото не посносил? )

Может в PHP есть готовые инструменты, или на плюсах, шарпе, джаве?...

Comment: Зная особенности формата JPЕG, достаточно проверить голову и хвост. Голова будет BOF `FF D8` а хвост EOF будет `FF D9`. В наше время частая проблеме - отсутствие хвоста. Если нужно проверять потроха - то чуть сложнее.

Comment: @nick_n_a, спасибо, сейчас буду пробовать

Comment: Добавлю: чтобы проверить "потороха", надо декодировать каждый файл при помощи libjpeg или другой библиотеки, которая умеет рапортовать об ошибках распаковки.

Comment: @zed, хорошая идея! Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за подсказки в комментариях. Решил вопрос через модуль PHP GD так:

`if (FALSE===imagecreatefromjpeg($photo)) ...`

Всё - чёрные квадраты пропали. От валидных но искажённых внутри фоток это конечно не спасло, но "совсем поломанные" удалил.